# Redirect System.out.println to AngularJS UI

Tags: java, angularjs

I have a scenario where I have an object/string that I'm printing using `System.out.println` in a loop to the console.

Now I added an AngularJS UI and want to redirect this output to the UI.

So, how can I pass a java object which is being updated continuously to Angular?

I have something like,

```
BuildImageResultCallback callback = new BuildImageResultCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onNext(BuildResponseItem item){
                System.out.println("It's done - > " + item);
                super.onNext(item);
            }
        };
```

I want `item` to be routed to an AngularJS UI. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use Websocket or html5 server push.

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera Could you point me to some helpful tutorials?

Comment: here you can see an example with Spring https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

Comment: Yeah this is similar to what I was looking for, thanks. But, I understand `@SendTo` only forwards the returned data but since my object is being dynamically updated, how can I route this?